# unable to build the cordova android apk through gitlab cicd pipeline

Tags: android, gitlab, cordova-3

unable to build the Cordova android apk through GitLab cicd pipeline, but same i tired manually through cmd or PowerShell it is working properly.

This are the commands i am using in yml and cmd

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@8.1.0
codova build android
```

[image]

in the error unable to find the file but the file is present in the location.